# saving checkbox state in listview in android?

Tags: android

I am fetching playlist from my mobile and showing my songs in listview along with multiple checkboxes..Now, i need to save state of checkboxes which will be reloaded when user again start the app.can you suggest how this can be done ??

for fetching songs from system playlist ...code that i have written is:

```
ListView list = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.songlist);
String[] projection = { MediaStore.Audio.Playlists.Members._ID,
                MediaStore.Audio.Playlists.Members.TITLE,
                 MediaStore.Audio.Playlists.Members.DATA,
                MediaStore.Audio.Playlists.Members.AUDIO_ID,
                MediaStore.Audio.Playlists.Members.ARTIST };

    Cursor cursor = managedQuery(
            // 1 is the id of playlist  MediaStore.Audio.Playlists.Members.getContentUri("external", 1), projection,
                MediaStore.Audio.Media.IS_MUSIC + " != 0 ", null, null);

SimpleCursorAdapter a = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this, R.layout.list_item, cursor,
                new String[] { MediaStore.Audio.Playlists.Members.TITLE }, new int[] { R.id.checkbox });
        this.setListAdapter(a);
        list.setAdapter(a);
```

Answer (score 1):

You could override the `onDestroy` method of your Activity, saving the contents of your adapter to a file. See http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html for reference on how to save to a file. You can easily access the adapater's contents using `getItem(int position)` on your SimpleAdapter.

Answer (score 0):

This should be helpful http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html